# Preventing multiple executions

Tags: python, django, locking, cron-task

I have this Django cron job script (I am using kronos for that, which is great).

Since I trigger this job every minute, I want to make sure that there isn't another instance of the script already running. If there is a previous job running, then I want to skip the current execution.

I know I can do that with a lock file, but that's not very reliable and can cause problems when you reboot in the middle of an execution (you have to clear the lock file), etc.

What's the best way to do this using Python (Django in this case)?

**EDIT:** I am targeting Linux, sorry for leaving this out.

Comment: On what platform? A lock-file is perfectly reliable on most Unix/Linux platforms these days: use os.open with O_CREAT|O_EXCL which guarantees only a single process has access to the file and a path which corresponds to a memory or swap based filesystem (like tmpfs: /tmp on Solaris, /run or /var/run on Linux) which solves your reboot concerns. The only potential issue is if your process crashes, doesn't clean up, etc...

Comment: Another option would be to use a kernel-based semaphore.

Comment: Sorry guys, Linux :-)

Comment: I'd also love to know this :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a Django app here: https://github.com/jsocol/django-cronjobs

Also available on pip as `cronjobs`.

Just in case you go straight to pip; You register jobs using the decorator like so:

```
# myapp/cron.py
import cronjobs

@cronjobs.register
def periodic_task():
    pass
```

Then run the command via:

```
$ ./manage.py cron periodic_task
```

It has job locking by default but you can disable it when you apply the decorator:

```
@register(lock=False)
```